# How do I have this function output starting on row 2 instead of row 1

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm creating a google sheet that pulls data from multiple sheets and organizes it under labeled header columns, I want this formula to output starting at row 2 because I want row 1 to be frozen and stay as column titles

I'm just not familiar at all with scripts so I'm sure there's an easy solution

```
function collectSheetsInfo() {
  const SHEETS = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheets();
  var info = SHEETS.map(
    (sheet, index) => [sheet.getName(), '=INDIRECT(A' + index + ' & "!B20")']
  );
  info.shift();  // remove index sheet info-row from the collection
  SHEETS[0].getRange(1, 1, info.length, info[0].length).setValues(info);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I gather the question involves how to change the index.

```
function collectSheetsInfo() {
  const shts = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheets();
  var info = shts.filter((_, i) => i > 0).map((sh, i) => [sh.getName(), '=INDIRECT(A' + ++i + ' & "!B20")']);
  shts[0].getRange(1, 1, info.length, info[0].length).setValues(info);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, this worked great except column B is offset by one cell, the data in B2 is in B3, B3 in B4, etc. How do i fix this?

Comment: I need to be able to see what the problem is and if you are going to answer don't wait a week.